# Adding title to page with instant jQuery search script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a Google Instant style search script written in jQuery. When the user queries, #**SEARCHTERM** is added onto my page URL. I was wondering how I could add the users query into the title of my page so it would be "**SEARCHTERM** - My Search Script"

Here is my current code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search").keyup(function(){
        var search=$(this).val();
        var keyword=encodeURIComponent(search);
        var yt_url='search.php?q='+keyword+'&category=web';
        window.location.hash=keyword;

        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:yt_url,
            dataType:"html",
            success:function(response){
                $("#result").html(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign title with: `document.title`

```
document.title = $(this).val() + " - My Search Script";
```

Comment: right after `window.location.hash=keyword;` for example. depends if you want the title to update right on search start, or when the results appear.